# Upload file using Axis2 Webservice get stuck because of strange definition of File class

Tags: web-services, client, jax-ws, apache-axis, mtom

I am trying to upload a file using web service (web service is required). Here is my [server code](http://pastebin.com/hHHmiXA7). Here is my [client code](http://pastebin.com/fGAfH9u8). The wsdl is [here](http://pastebin.com/xLR3HR4g) (I used XML online formater to beautify it but it trimmed the `wsdl:` part

I keep getting the following trace stack complaining about my file

```
rg.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.io.File
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:446)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at server.ServerStub.uploadFile(ServerStub.java:175)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:53)
```

I have noticed that in the stub file, the File class is not a `java.io.File` but `public static class File implements org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean`

How can I make the service understand the standard File.io?
Regards